# Drag and drop sprites across transparent window overlay

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I made the game into a transparent window overlay using Windows API. I added a sprite (which is the default white square) and want to add functionality so that when I click and drag it across the screen using LMB, I can drag the sprite with me and release so that it just falls back to the bottom of the screen. The basic falling physics are done, I just need to code the drag-and-drop part. I’ve tried a typical solution, but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseInteractions : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 offset;
    private bool dragging;

    void Update()
    {
        if (dragging)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 newPosition = ray.GetPoint(10) + offset;
            transform.position = newPosition;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        Event e = Event.current;
        Vector2 mousePos = e.mousePosition;
        if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 0)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.transform == transform)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                offset = transform.position - hit.point;
                dragging = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.type == EventType.MouseUp && e.button == 0)
        {
            dragging = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Windows API script to make transparent window overlay

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class WindowSetting : MonoBehaviour
{
    IntPtr window;

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const uint WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    const uint LWA_COLORKEY = 0x00000001;

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

    private struct MARGINS
    {
        public int cxLeftWidth;
        public int cxRightWidth;
        public int cyTopHeight;
        public int cyBottomHeight;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern uint DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS margins);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

    void Start()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR_
        window = GetActiveWindow();

        MARGINS margins = new MARGINS() { cxLeftWidth = -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(window, ref margins);

        SetWindowLong(window, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED);

        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, crKey: 0, bAlpha: 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

        SetWindowPos(window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        Application.runInBackground = true;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: probably depends on whatever you did via Windows API ... can you show us that bit because I suspect you have set some flag that routes the user input to whatever is behind your transparent window

Comment: @derHugo Just added the script. I'm 90% sure at this point the "drag-and-drop" functionality I'm going for will also involve Windows API in the MouseInteractions script in some way, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Slight edit: I've figured out the issue behind the mouse only clicking what's below the game window, but the main problem of not being able to drag and drop the sprite is still there.